# How to display contact anniversaries in MacOS Calendar?

Tags: macos, contacts, calendar

Is there a way to pull in anniversaries for contacts to the Birthday calendar or another calendar in the MacOS Calendar app?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new calendar with, say, Google, import the anniversaries into that calendar, then subscribe to that calendar with Apple Calendar.